# Jupyter does not recognize class declaration

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In a Jupyter cell, I have this class:

```
class Shirt:

    def __init__(self, shirt_color, shirt_size, shirt_style, shirt_price):
        self.color = shirt_color
        self.size = shirt_size
        self.style = shirt_style
        self.price = shirt_price
    
    def change_price(self, new_price):
    
        self.price = new_price
        
    def discount(self, discount):

        return self.price * (1 - discount)
```

And when I do this:

```
import Shirt as shirt

shirt.color = 'red'
shirt.size = 'S'
shirt.style = 'long-sleeve'
shirt.price = 25
```

I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-d95b669ecd57> in <module>()
----> 5 import Shirt as shirt
      6 
      7 shirt.color = 'red'

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Shirt'
```

I am running the cell that declares the class Shirt so I don't know why its not recognizing it.

Comment: Why do you believe you should be able to `import Shirt`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you create an object. You must do

```
shirt = Shirt('red', 'S', 'long-sleeve', 25)
```

Comment: Okay but its not even recognizing my import.

Comment: You don't need `import`, you use it to import modules, you're creating a *class*.

Comment: @oo92 there's *no need to import anything*. In any case, your import doesn't make sense... What connection do you believe there is between importable modules and some class definition?